# VSCode Connection Refused after change from wsl to wsl2

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I have installed WSL2 and changed my Ubuntu WSL Version from 1 to 2
after this change I can't connect from vscode to wsl2 ubuntu and following error has been occurred
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted .vscode directory in my home and reinstall it.
then the problem has been fixed